How to perform conditional poisson regression for a 1:5 matched cohort study?
I have a matched cohort population using data that spans the years 2016-2021. My exposure of interest is continuous dialysis treatment, and my outcome is e.coli infections (count outcome). Each time an individual becomes exposed, 5 unexposed individuals are sampled from the general population, exact matched on age and sex, The purpose of implementing this matching procedure was originally just to have comparable distribution of age, sex, and index/inclusion date distribution between the exposed and unexposed groups. The estimate I want is an incidence rate ratio. At the moment, my unexposed individuals are followed for the same amount of time as the exposed they were matched to. This introduces a sort of dependency in my matched sets, because the follow-up time of the unexposed is dependent on how long the matched exposed is undergoing treatment, which is quite variable across the entire dataset. I have been advised to try to do a conditional Poisson regression, conditioning on the matched sets. Does anyone have experience with this, and can direct me to the correct packages or sources? I was told that this can be done by simply adding an additional variable to my regression and using the gnm package, but while reading documentation for the gnm package, it's not quite adding up to me. Any help is appreciated.
Something to note: I did not use Matchit for my matched sampling.
